# Category headings of each product in a dropdown list with products as subs

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the category headings of each product in a dropdown list, with all the categories products as subs, these are all linked to a customer.

I have 2 tables in my database, one which contains the categories and products and then the other has the customer information that has all the products linked to the customer.

I am not sure where i am going wrong in the below code. The output is as follows:

**Category 1**

- Product 1

**Category 2**

- Product 2

**Category 3**

- Product 3

**Category 2**

- Product 4

Whereas i need it to be as below:

**Category 1**

- Product 1

**Category 2**

- Product 2
- Product 4

**Category 3**

- Product 3

**Code**

```
<?php

$customer_id = "27";

?>

<select>
<?php
$records = mysqli_query($conn_register, "SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$customer_id '");
while ($get_value = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
    $product = $get_value['product'];

    $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM addproducts WHERE `name` LIKE '$product'";
    $result_1 = $conn_register->query($sql_1);
    $data = $result_1->fetch_assoc();

    $groups[$data['category']][$get_value['product']] = $get_value['product'];
    foreach ($groups as $label => $opt) { ?>

        <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
            <?php foreach ($opt as $id => $name) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </optgroup>

<?php 

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The first thing a proper _control break_ implementation needs, is for the data to be properly sorted by the break criterion/criteria - but you don't even appear to be applying _any_ ordering of the data you are selecting there anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the records by using **order by** like this

```sql
"SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$customer_id ' 
order by category, product_id"
```

Then the list will be sorted by category and then product_id